# How to add 1dp border (to an image) so that it works on all screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, border, android-imageview

I'm looking for the simplest, reliable way to add a thin (1dp) border to an element—in this case `ImageView`— on API level 14+.

To my understanding, **layer lists** are the way to do this kind of stuff.

So, what I have:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay_main_character"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_width="72dp"        
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    />
```

In Java, the ImageView is set to display [this 200x200 px image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIQrB.jpg) <sup>([Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Citrus_fruits.jpg))</sup>.

And in `res/drawable/image_border.xml`:

```
<!-- Adds thin (1dp) border, and nothing else. -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:top="1dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" />
            <padding android:right="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

What it looks like on a test device (Galaxy Note, Android 4.1.2):

[image]

**Left and bottom borders are missing.**

What am I doing wrong? Is my layer list approach incorrect (or could it be simplified)? Or can this be achieved using something else than layer lists?

Comment: you can set background color for your imageView and set padding of ImageView to 1dp.

Comment: @Demand: that seems to work nicely. Add it as an answer!

Comment: I have added it. Mark it as solve please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set background color for your `ImageView` and set padding to 1dp:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay_main_character"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_width="72dp"        
    android:background="#F000"
    android:padding="1dp"
    />
```

It will look like you want.

Comment: will that not cause overdraw once you set a image drawable to this imageview ?

Answer (score 2):

While [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19812862/56285) is simple and works great in general, it has one shortcoming in the case of *images that are fetched over network* (in a background thread). While the image is still loading, a **big black square is shown**, which is not necessarily what you want.

[A colleague of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943982/antti-lammi) pointed out that in such cases you could do this instead: add a `FrameLayout` "behind" the image for the border, and set the `ImageView` background to  white (for example), like so:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay_main_character"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In our case, the in-progress look is much better this way:

[image]

---

### Addendum: custom "bordered image" component

Actually, besides the 1dp border, we also wanted to *animate* showing the image (alpha 0 -> 1) after it had been loaded over network; something like:

```
imageView.setAlpha(0f); 
imageView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500).start();
```

For the animation to look good (in our app at least), the background should be white instead of black.

To support *both* the border and animation, I'd have to add *another* FrameLayout (with white background), between the image and the outer (border) FrameLayout. But the XML gets quite verbose, so we created a custom reusable component for this in Java: "**BorderedImage**".

```
package fi.company.product.ui.helpers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

/**
 * Custom ImageView (technically custom FrameLayout) with black 1dp border, 
 * white background and support for alpha animation (white -> image)
 *
 * @author Jonik, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19818328/56285
 */
public class BorderedImage extends FrameLayout {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public BorderedImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public BorderedImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public BorderedImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        // Outer FrameLayout for the black border
        setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        int padding1dp = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
        setPadding(padding1dp, padding1dp, padding1dp, padding1dp);

        // Another FrameLayout for the white background 
        FrameLayout middleLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
        middleLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
        middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        addView(middleLayout);

        // The actual ImageView
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
        middleLayout.addView(imageView);
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Of course, it would easy to further customise this helper: for example, pass border & background colours as constructor parameters.

Now, it's simple to use BorderedImage in XML:

```
<fi.company.product.ui.helpers.BorderedImage
    android:id="@+id/overlay_main_character"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_width="72dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="1dp" >
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay_main_character"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_width="72dp"        
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        />
```